# Geary Mail is failing to send mail from gmail

Tags: email, 17.10, gmail, geary

I have been having this problem a lot lately and it really is getting my nerve.  I even went as far as deleting all the files including hidden config files yet nothing has been able to alter this so it will work again.  I will include a log file next time I open it up, but I do need to know where to look.

Comment: AH, Google....
One thing I found was this: go to Google email, somewhere in settings, and approve "access from 'less secure' devices". I know.... this is Googles view of the world, but you may need to do this.

Google view anything that is not Google as less secure. I use Evolution and had a similar problem until I changed this setting [then closed my Google account] and it may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a debug log if you run Geary from a terminal using the command `geary -d`

However as @Piloti said GMail is no longer compatible with standard IMAP and SMTP by default, hence you may need to update your Google Account settings to get it working correctly. See the [Geary FAQ entry about GMail](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Geary/FAQ#Connecting_to_GMail) for details.

Comment: Allowing less secure apps was previously enabled.  Here is a copy of the log: http://tomhancock.000webhostapp.com/Log-Geary

Comment: From that log it looks like you have a message in your outbox that is causing Geary's outbound queue to get wedged, but not giving much more detail than that. It also seems like you're using geary built from git master - is that right? If so, can you try building the `wip/713006-better-error-reporting` branch and see if that reports what the actual problem is?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: In a terminal window: `git clone https://git.gnome.org/browse/geary && cd geary && git checkout wip/713006-better-error-reporting`, then follow the directions in the [INSTALL file](https://git.gnome.org/browse/geary/tree/INSTALL). If you run into any problems with that, please [get in touch](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Geary/Contact) on the mailing list or IRC.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the message from the cue so I can test another message to see if I could send it?

Comment: Yep, if you select it in the outbox and then delete it using the delete button on the toolbar, it will be removed (and lost permanently).

Comment: Oh PS, the better error reporting has landed on the main development branch (master), so there's no need to check out the WIP branch any more.

Answer (score 0):

i just found the thread ... facing the same problem.

the solution for me was to enable pop and imap in gmail (settings -> see all settings -> Forewarding and POP/IMAP)

I left the default settins as is (geary & gmail) - the only thing I noticed is, that I had to kill geary process.

Closing didn't end it in background - after killing it and restarting it, sending was possible again.

hope it helps somebody ;)